# Naming N:N connectivity tables

Tags: database, naming-conventions

We have 2 object types and want to connect them N:N.
For example, articles & authors.

1. How would you name relations table?
2. What would you put first at table name, articles or authors? (articles2authors or books2authors)

Someone would, probably, recognize this question as stupid. I don't think so because I'm looking for ideal naming convention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose [any](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

- Junction Table
- Cross-Reference Table
- Bridge Table
- Join Table
- Map Table
- Link Table

, but please do not use '2' to replace 'to', which is so 1970.

I personally prefer `Junction`: `AuthorsArticlesJunction`, `AuthorsBooksJunction`. I put `Authors` first because without an author neither article, nor book would not exist. This is somewhat metaphysical, but works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer map - so something like AUTHOR_ARTICLE_MAP, when used consistently, explains how the table is used.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `AuthorArticle`.  Generally the 'primary' object should go first (if one can be determined), but the ordering is not a big deal.

Comment: The only problem I have with this approach is that it doesn't identify the table as anything special, which is why I like my "special" tables to have a common ending - i.e. MAP, JOIN, etc.  I find it does help, especially when you have to come back to something 6 months later.

Comment: Yeah, that is true, adding some common value can help identify the table as one of the 'N:N'/associative tables.  For me, I am used to one of those table being named with the Object1_Object2 syntax.  Even if the name of the table isn't identifiable as a 'N:N' table (which it should be when it's made up of two major objects), a quick look at the table structure and seeing fields author_id and article_id should make it clear.  It just comes down to personal naming preference.

Answer (score 1):

1) article_has_author (just my "privat" convention)m or ArticleAuthor
2) in n:m relations it normaly doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the logical relations , for example:

- Article_Author
- Links , UserRoles -> LinksForUserRoles / Links_For_UserRoles
- User , Role - > UserRole